# How can I name "a[[i]]" the parts of Table "a"? Or how to make Table "a" grow inside FindMinimum?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I want to minimize a function that uses a `Table` named `a` with the Conjugate Gradient Method of `FindMinimum`.

*Instinctively* I do the following :

```
FindMinimum[(Sum[a[[i]]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 2}])^2, {a, {0, 0}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

But I obviously get the following messages and results :

> During evaluation of In[135]:= Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>   During evaluation of In[135]:= Part::partd: Part specification a[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>
> {0., {a -> {0., 0.}}}

So, to overcome this *little* difficulty, I tried the following :

```
a = {a1, a2};
FindMinimum[(Sum[a[[i]]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 2}])^2, {a, {0, 0}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

> During evaluation of In[136]:= Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>   During evaluation of In[136]:= Part::partd: Part specification a[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>
> {0., {{a1, a2} -> {0., 0.}}}

and again I obtain the same error messages. So I came down to the *dirty* manner:

```
FindMinimum[(a1*Cos[1.3] + a2*Cos[1.3])^2, {{a1, 2}, {a2, 0}}, 
  Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

which this time provided me with actual results :

```
{2.86222*10^-17, {a1 -> 1., a2 -> -1.}}
```

Now, while this last alternative works for this simple example and for a Table containing only two values, It will become impossible if I had to do for example:

```
FindMinimum[(Sum[a[[i]]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 1000}])^2, {a, {0, 0}}, 
  Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

How can I sort this out? I'm aware that there might something wrong with my approach, but I can't find another manner to set this up.

Comment: Note that you *did* get correct results in all three attempts.  (The constant `Cos[1.3]` can be factored out of your example, showing that any set of numbers summing to zero is a valid solution.)

Comment: @whuber oops... you're right! In fact even with the warnings and stuff, it works! Just tested it with some other *toy models* and it gives the right solutions... Only problem is that it takes unexpectedly long time to converge...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution (maybe to specific) to your example is to  consider `Sum[a[[i]]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 2}]`
as the dot product a . {Cos[1.3],Cos[1.3]}.

Then the problem becomes :

```
FindMinimum[(a . {Cos[1.3], Cos[1.3]}) ^2, {a, {2, 0}},Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

which is a syntax Mathematica accepts. It gives :

```
{1.,-1.}
```

Of course, it can be extended to more variables

Comment: (+1) that's the cleanest solution (I think *Mathematica* used to be unable to do this, but it got cleverer...)

Answer (score 6):

This kind of question gets asked very often. You can do this:

```
up = 5;
varlst = {a@#, 0.1} & /@ Range[up];
FindMinimum[(Total@Table[a[i]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, up}])^2, varlst, 
 Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

does the job.

The reason your attempt does not work is that, if `a` is not defined, `a[[4]]` attempts to take the 4th part of the symbol `a`; but `a` has length 1, and its only part is `a[[0]]` which is `Symbol`, its head... So I replaced `a[[i]]` by `a[i]`, which creates an expression with head `a` and `i` on the branch (the important point is that `a[4]` is a perfectly normal variable, for purposes of this discussion).

I also replaced `Sum` by `Total@Table[]` because Mathematica tries to do clever things with `Sum`, while `Total@Table[]` just constructs the list and adds the terms.

The `varlst = {a@#, 0.1} & /@ Range[up];` could also have been written `varlst=Table[{a[i], 0.1}, {i, 1, up}]`; it just constructs the last argument of `FindRoot` before the options.

Comment: Actually `a[[0]]` is not `a`, it's `Symbol`, which is really the `Head` of `a`

Comment: @RunnyKine right, fixed

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get your code to work is this:

```
a = Array["a", 2];

Clear[a, c];
a = Array[c, 2];
FindMinimum[(Sum[Evaluate@a[[i]]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 2}])^2, 
 Thread@{a, {2, 0}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]

{2.86222*10^-17, {c[1] -> 1., c[2] -> -1.}}
```

Here, I maintained the array `a` the way you wanted it in the sum, but had to add an `Evaluate` because `Sum` has attribute `HoldAll` so that it doesn't look up the values of its arguments (including `a[[i]]`) initially.

In `FindMinimum`, you then have to make sure that the variables represented by `a` have the correct number. If `a` isn't assigned any values beforehand, that doesn't work. So I precede the minimization by the assignment `a = Array[c, 2]` where now `c[1]` and `c[2]` are inserted as the entries of array `a`. The starting values are then formulated in terms of `a`, but they really are initial conditions for the `c[i]`. To set those, I use `Thread` to make the assignments pairwise for each member of the array `a` and of the value list `{2, 0}`.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* 10 introduces [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html) allowing this without error messages:

```
FindMinimum[(Sum[Indexed[a, i]*Cos[1.3], {i, 1, 2}])^2, {a, {2, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {3.97214*10^-18, {a -> {1., -1.}}}
> ```